# How can I limit ModelAdmin queryset to user-editable items when using object permissions?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to implement Florian's [object permissions system](http://djangoadvent.com/1.2/object-permissions/) from his article on Django Advent, but I'm running into an issue trying to limit the queryset returned to only items the user has permission to edit/view. Florian mentions it in his section on wrapping the admin, but skips over it. I can't see a good way to filter the queryset. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
class ObjectPermission(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    can_view = models.BooleanField()
    can_change = models.BooleanField()
    can_delete = models.BooleanField()

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

you can filter your query set in this way (in your method queryset):

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(YourModelAdmin, self).queryset(request)
    op = ObjectPermission.objects.filter(user=request.user, can_change=True, content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(YourModel)).values_list('object_id').distinct()
    qs = queryset.filter(id__in=[id[0] for id in op])
    return qs
```

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I know how to customize the admin queryset, but I can't sort out the actual query syntax one would need to use to do it with Florian's object permissions implementation.

Comment: Brooks, sorry, i misunderstood the question, but i fix my answer